# Converting .p12 to .pem in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, certificate

I am trying to convert my .p12 certificate to .pem. I exported it from Firefox and put it on my Desktop in Ubuntu. Now I tried to run the following commands.

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in MyCertificate.p12 -out newfile.pem
```

I get an error message stating that Can't open MyCertificate.p12 for reading, Not such file or directory.
How come it is not a file when it is on the Desktop?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it using

**keystore explorer**

download and install keystore explorer from here

[Link](https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer/releases/download/v5.4.2/kse_5.4.2_all.deb)

> Open keystore explorer -> Goto files -> open -> select the .p12 file

it will prompt for password (if there is no password just hit Enter)

> Rightclick on the keystore goto export -> export key pair -> it will
>   prompt for password (if there is no password just hit Enter)
>
> check the **PEM** format click export